# Streaming camera via websockets in fastAPI

Tags: python, websocket, video-streaming, fastapi

Hi all i have simple fastapi endpoint that streams camera feed to HTML page. Everything works great on the first time, but I can't reload the page and when I'm closing the page i get

```
websockets.exceptions.connectionclosederror no close frame received or sent
```

And when enter the page again stream does not loads

here is my code

```py
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})

async def get_video_frame(camera):
    while True:
        success, frame = camera.read()
        if not success:
            break

        _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        yield buffer.tobytes()

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def get_stream(websocket: WebSocket, camera=Depends(lambda: camera)):
    await websocket.accept()
    try:
        async for frame in get_video_frame(camera):
            await websocket.send_bytes(frame)
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        await websocket.close(code=1000)
        print("Client disconnected")
    finally:
        camera.release()
```

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Live Streaming</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="frame" src="">
        <script>
            let ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws");
            let image = document.getElementById("frame");

            image.onload = function(){
                URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
            };

            ws.onmessage = function(event) {
                image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.data);
            };

            ws.onclose = function(event) {
                console.log("WebSocket closed:", event);
            };

            window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
                ws.close();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

removing

```
code=1000
finally
or 
camera=Depends(lambda: camera)
```

does nothing

and when i run

```
ws.close()
```

stream stops but nothing is printed out in the server